# How to send outbound media message (pdf) in twilio using template

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I want to send transactional notice pdf messages whatsapp that too outbound. I read docs and found out, it is done using using content api.
I wanted to send something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrLIy.png)

so the template i have created looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64rk5.png)

so when i am sending the media message using this template

```
client.messages
      .create({
         from: 'MGXXXXXXXXXXX',
         contentSid: 'HXXXXXXXXXXX',
         contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
           1: 'Kushagra Agrawal',
           2: 'Mon Jun 19 2023 10:10:54 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)',
           3: 'attachment.pdf?alt=media&token=XXXXXXXXXXXX'
         }),
         to: 'whatsapp:+91mynumber'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

the code is running fine and giving me sid but i am not recieving the message.

I tried sending direct using mediaURL but as expected that also did not work.

Comment: Can you check the message log in the Twilio console to see what it says? Maybe there is an error code with a description.

Comment: its showing, error: null, price:null, status:accepted, errorCode:null.

Comment: I tried different ways, but I am only getting the status of "accepted" or "queued" but not receiving any messages on WhatsApp.